# Laravel blade @extends doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have strange issue in laravel blade  everything works normally until  I edit something in the file  the master layout stop loading correctly for no reason 
sometime the page html content  load partially

It works fine on localhost but on the server

I stopped cloudflare and all caches

As I said the issue occurs only when I edit some file  only that page stop working the other pages works normally unless I edit them or add something to them

I hope you can help me.

master file

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>

    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="{{asset('../storage/app/public/Favicon_reviews.png')}}">
    <title>
        {{(is_array(($web_title ?? ''))? $web_title[1]  ?? '': $web_title ?? '') ?? 'Home'}}

    </title>


    {{--foundation css--}}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/foundation.css')}}">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/dashboard.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/style.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/dripicon.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/typicons.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/font-awesome.min.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/theme.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/jquery.toastmessage.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('js/circle-progress/jquery.circliful.css')}}">

    <!-- pace loader -->
    {{--for top blue line loader--}}
    <script src="{{asset('js/pace/pace.js')}}"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('js/pace/themes/green/pace-theme-flash.css')}}">
    {{--<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('js/pace/themes/templates/pace-theme-barber-shop.tmpl.css')}}">--}}
    {{--    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('js/pace/themes/green/pace-theme-big-counter.css')}}">--}}
    {{--end pace--}}

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('js/slicknav/slicknav.css')}}">
    {{--to support effects in old broswer--}}
    <script src="{{asset('js/vendor/modernizr.js')}}"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/main-style.css')}}">
    {{--js scripts--}}
    @yield('css')
</head>

<body>
<!-- preloader -->
<div id="preloader">
    <div id="status">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<!-- End of preloader -->

<div class="off-canvas-wrap content" data-offcanvas>
    <!-- right sidebar wrapper -->
    <div class="inner-wrap">

        <!-- Right sidemenu -->
        <div id="skin-select">
            <!--      Toggle sidemenu icon button -->
            <a id="toggle">
                <span class="fa icon-menu"></span>
            </a>
            <!--      End of Toggle sidemenu icon button -->

            <div class="skin-part">
                <div id="tree-wrap">
                    @include('main.left-nav')
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end of Rightsidemenu -->

        <div class="wrap-fluid" id="paper-bg">
            <!-- top nav -->
            <div class="top-bar-nest">
                <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation" data-options="is_hover: false">
                    @include('main.top-nav')
                </nav>
            </div>
            <!-- end of top nav -->

            <!-- breadcrumbs -->
            <ul class="breadcrumbs ">
                <li><a href="{{url('/')}}"><span style="    font-size: 15px; position: relative; top: -3px;"
                                                 class="fa fa-home"></span></a>
                </li>
                @if(is_array(($web_title ?? false)))
                    @foreach($web_title as $title)
                        <li>
                            {!! $title ?? '' !!}
                        </li>
                    @endforeach
                @else
                    <li>
                        {{$web_title ?? ''}}
                    </li>
                @endif

                {{--<li>{{$web_title}}
                </li>--}}
            </ul>
            <!-- end of breadcrumbs -->

            <!-- Container Begin -->
            <div class="row" style="margin-top:-20px">
                @yield('container')
            </div>
            <!-- End of Container Begin -->

            @include('main.footer')
        </div>

        <!-- Right Menu -->
        <aside class="right-off-canvas-menu">
            {{--@include('main.right-nav')--}}
        </aside>
        <!-- close the off-canvas menu -->
        <a class="exit-off-canvas"></a>
        <!-- End of Right Menu -->
    </div>
    <!-- end paper bg -->

</div>
<!-- end of off-canvas-wrap -->

<!-- end of inner-wrap -->

<!-- main javascript library -->

<script src="{{asset('/js/jquery.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('/js/waypoints.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('/js/preloader-script.js')}}"></script>
<!-- foundation javascript -->
<script src="{{asset('/js/foundation.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('/js/foundation/foundation.dropdown.js')}}"></script>

<!-- main edumix javascript -->
{{--add scroll bar to divs--}}
<script src="{{asset('/js/slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.js')}}"></script>
{{--mobile menu--}}
<script src="{{asset('/js/slicknav/jquery.slicknav.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('/js/sliding-menu.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('/js/scriptbreaker-multiple-accordion-1.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('/js/number/jquery.counterup.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('/js/circle-progress/jquery.circliful.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('/js/jquery.toastmessage.js')}}"></script>

<script src="{{asset('/js/app.js')}}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function ($) {
        "use strict";


    })(jQuery);
</script>

<script>
    $(document).foundation();
</script>

<script>
    /*helper functions*/

    function confirm(title, message, callback) {
        // create your modal template
        var modal = '<div class="reveal-modal tiny" id="confirmation" data-reveal aria-labelledby="modalTitle" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog" data-animation-in="slide-in-down">' +
            '<h2>' + title + '</h2>' +
            '<p class="lead">' + message + '</p>' +
            '<button class="button success yes" style="margin-right: 50px;">Yes</button>' +
            '<button class="button alert float-right close-reveal" >No</button>' +
            '</div>';
        // appending new reveal modal to the page
        $('body').append(modal);
        // registergin this modal DOM as Foundation reveal
        /*   var confirmation = new Foundation.Reveal($('#confirmation'));
         // open
         confirmation.open();*/
        var confirm_selector = $('#confirmation');
        confirm_selector.foundation('reveal', 'open');
        // listening for yes click

        confirm_selector.children('.yes').on('click', function () {
            // close and REMOVE FROM DOM to avoid multiple binding
            confirm_selector.foundation('reveal', 'close');
            confirm_selector.remove();
            // calling the function to process
            callback.call();
        });
        $(document).on('closed.zf.reveal', '#confirmation', function () {
            // remove from dom when closed

            confirm_selector.foundation('reveal', 'close');
        });
    }

    $(document).on('click', '.close-reveal', function () {

        $('#confirmation').foundation('reveal', 'close');

    });
</script>

{{--header javascript--}}

{{--search process img--}}
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#search_form').submit(function (e) {
            $('#search_loading').show();
        });
    });
</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#contact_us_form').submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('.message_button').prop('disabled', true);
            $.ajax({
                url: '{{url('/contact_us')}}',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
//                    console.log(data);
                    $().toastmessage('showToast', {
                        text: data.success,
                        stayTime: 3000,
                        sticky: false,
                        position: 'top-center',
                        type: 'success',
                        closeText: '',
                        close: null
                    });
                    $('.message_button').prop('disabled', false);
                    $('#requests').foundation('reveal', 'close');
                    $("#contact_us_form")[0].reset();
                }
            });
        })
    });
</script>
{{--request form--}}


<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#requests_form').submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('.message_button').prop('disabled', true);
            $.ajax({
                url: '{{url('/contact_us')}}',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    $().toastmessage('showToast', {
                        text: data.success,
                        stayTime: 3000,
                        sticky: false,
                        position: 'top-center',
                        type: 'success',
                        closeText: '',
                        close: null
                    });
                    $('.message_button').prop('disabled', false);
                    $('#requests').foundation('reveal', 'close');
                    $("#requests_form")[0].reset();
                }
            });
        })
    });
</script>


<script>

    $('.input_option').change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == 'tag') {
            $('.tag_messages').html('You can add more then one tag by adding comma Ex(tag1,tag2,.....)');
        } else {
            $('.tag_messages').html('');
        }
    });

</script>

<script>
    var textarea = null;
    window.addEventListener("load", function () {
        textarea = window.document.querySelector("#contact_area");
        textarea.addEventListener("keypress", function () {
            if (textarea.scrollTop != 0) {
                textarea.style.height = textarea.scrollHeight + "px";
            }
        }, false);
    }, false);
</script>
<script>
    var textarea = null;
    window.addEventListener("load", function () {
        textarea = window.document.querySelector("#contact_area1");
        textarea.addEventListener("keypress", function () {
            if (textarea.scrollTop != 0) {
                textarea.style.height = textarea.scrollHeight + "px";
            }
        }, false);
    }, false);
</script>
@yield('javascript')
</body>
</html>
```

Home page

```
@extends('main.master')



@section('container')

    <div class="row" style="margin-top:-20px">
        <div class="large-12 columns">
            <blockquote style="border-right: 3px solid #8c92a3;text-align: center;margin-top: 5px;">
                Thank you for installing the application, please take a moment of your time and rate the app. It will help us to improve the application for you.
                <a>Rate Here</a>
            </blockquote>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" >
        <div class="large-8 columns">
            <div class="box bg-transparent ">
                <!-- /.box-header -->
                <div class="box-header no-pad bg-transparent">

                    <h3 style="margin-bottom:20px;" class="box-title">
                        <span>Daily Visitors</span>
                    </h3>


                </div>
                <div class="box-body no-pad">

                    <div id="line-chart" style="height: 235px; padding: 0px; position: relative;">
                        <canvas class="flot-base"
                                style="direction: ltr; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 785px; height: 235px;"
                                width="863" height="258"></canvas>
                        <div class="flot-text"
                             style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; font-size: smaller; color: rgb(84, 84, 84);">
                            <div class="flot-x-axis flot-x1-axis xAxis x1Axis"
                                 style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; display: block;">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <canvas class="flot-overlay"
                                style="direction: ltr; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 785px; height: 235px;"
                                width="863" height="258"></canvas>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <!-- /.box-body -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.box -->
        </div>

        <div class="large-4 columns">
            <div class="box bg-transparent ">
                <!-- /.box-header -->
                <div class="box-header no-pad bg-transparent">

                    <h3 style="margin:0 20px 0 -5px;" class="box-title">
                        <span>Visitors</span>
                    </h3>


                </div>
                <div style="margin:15px 0 0" class="box-body no-pad">

                    <div class="stats-wrap">
                        <h2><b class="counter-up" style="color:#666;">{{$counter_visitors_data[0]['year'] ?? 0 }}</b> <span
                                    style="background:#666;">+<b
                                        class="counter-up">{{($counter_visitors_data[0]['year_rating'] ?? 0)   <= 100 ? ($counter_visitors_data[0]['year_rating']?? 0): 100 }}</b>%</span>
                        </h2>
                        <p class="text-grey">Total Visitors
                            <small>This Year vs last year</small>
                        </p>
                        <h4><b class="counter-up" style="color:#888;">{{$counter_visitors_data[1]['month'] ?? 0 }}</b> <span
                                    style="background:#888;">+<b
                                        class="counter-up">{{($counter_visitors_data[1]['month_rating'] ?? 0) <= 100 ? ($counter_visitors_data[0]['month_rating'] ?? 0):100}}</b>%</span>
                        </h4>
                        <p>New Visitors
                            <small>This Month</small>
                        </p>
                        <h4 style="color:#333;"><b class="counter-up">{{$counter_visitors_data[2]['week'] ?? 0 }}</b> <span
                                    style="background:#333;">+<b
                                        class="counter-up">{{($counter_visitors_data[2]['week_rating'] ?? 0)   <= 100 ? ($counter_visitors_data[0]['week_rating']?? 0):100}}</b></span></h4>
                        <p>New Visitors
                            <small>This week</small>
                        </p>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <!-- /.box-body -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.box -->
        </div>
    </div>

    {{------------------------------------------section 2---------------------------------------}}

    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 20px;">
        <div class="large-4 columns">
            <div class="box bg-transparent ">
                <!-- /.box-header -->
                <div class="box-header no-pad bg-transparent">

                    <h3 style="margin:0 20px 0 -5px;" class="box-title">
                        <span>Reviews</span>
                    </h3>


                </div>
                <div style="margin:15px 0 0" class="box-body no-pad">
                    <div class="stats-wrap">
                        <h2><b class="counter-up" style="color:#666;">{{$counter_reviews_data[0]['year'] ?? 0 }}</b> <span
                                    style="background:#666;">+<b
                                        class="counter-up">{{($counter_reviews_data[0]['year_rating'] ?? 0)  <= 100 ? ($counter_reviews_data[0]['year_rating']?? 0):100}}</b>%</span>
                        </h2>
                        <p class="text-grey">Total Reviews
                            <small>This Year vs last year</small>
                        </p>
                        <h4><b class="counter-up" style="color:#888;">{{$counter_reviews_data[1]['month']?? 0  }}</b> <span
                                    style="background:#888;">+<b
                                        class="counter-up">{{($counter_reviews_data[1]['month_rating'] ?? 0)  <= 100 ? ($counter_reviews_data[1]['month_rating']?? 0):100}}</b>%</span>
                        </h4>
                        <p>New Reviews
                            <small>This Month</small>
                        </p>
                        <h4 style="color:#333;"><b class="counter-up">{{$counter_reviews_data[2]['week']?? 0  }}</b> <span
                                    style="background:#333;">+<b
                                        class="counter-up">{{($counter_reviews_data[2]['week_rating'] ?? 0)   <= 100 ? ($counter_reviews_data[2]['week_rating']?? 0):100 }}</b>%</span></h4>
                        <p>New Reviews
                            <small>This week</small>
                        </p>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <!-- /.box-body -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.box -->
        </div>
        <div class="large-4 columns">
            <div class="bg-complete-profile">
                <span class="bg-green fa fa-star"></span>
                <!--   <img src="img/bag.png"> -->
                <h6 class="bg-black text-white"><strong><a href="https://apps.shopify.com/aliexpress-reviews-2"
                                                           style="color: #ffffff;">Rate Application</a></strong></h6>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="large-4 columns">
            <div class="bg-complete-profile">
                <span class="bg-green  fontello-doc-1"></span>
                <!-- <img src="img/box.png"> -->
                <h6 class="bg-black text-white"><a href="" style="color: #ffffff;">FAQ</a></h6>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="large-4 columns">
            <div class="bg-complete-profile">
                <span class="bg-green  icon-user-group"></span>
                <!--  <i class="img/count.png"></i> -->
                <h6 class="bg-black text-white"><a href="{{url('visitors')}}" style="color: #ffffff;">Latest
                        Visitors</a></h6>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="large-4 columns">
            <div class="bg-complete-profile">
                <span class="bg-green  fontello-params"></span>
                <!--  <i class="img/count.png"></i> -->
                <h6 class="bg-black text-white"><a href="{{url('General_options')}}" style="color: #ffffff;">Main
                        Setting</a></h6>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    {{------------------------------------------section 3---------------------------------------}}
    <div class="large-12 columns">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box-header bg-transparent">
                <!-- tools box -->
                <div class="pull-right box-tools">

                                    <span class="box-btn" data-widget="collapse"><i class="icon-minus"></i>
                                    </span>
                    <span class="box-btn" data-widget="remove"><i class="icon-cross"></i>
                                    </span>
                </div>
                <h3 class="box-title"><i class=" icon-calendar"></i>
                    <span>Latest Visitor</span>
                </h3>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-header -->
            <div class="box-body" style="display: block;">
                <style>
                    @media screen and (max-width: 1400px) {
                        .visitors_images {
                            left: 60% !important;
                        }
                    }

                    @media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
                        .visitors_images {
                            left: 50% !important;
                            top: 43px !important;
                        }
                    }

                    @media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
                        .visitors_images {
                            left: 65% !important;
                            top: 43px !important;
                        }
                    }


                </style>
                <div class="row">
                    <?php $counter = 0; ?>
                    @foreach($visitors as $visitor)
                        <?php
                        $product_id = $visitor['product_id'];
                        $country_code = $visitor['country_code'];

                        ?>
                        <div class="large-4 medium-6 small-12 columns" style="float: left !important;">
                            <div class="school-timetable">
                                <hr>
                                <h5><span style="background: #92CD18;">New</span><strong> Visitor </strong>For
                                    Product:<i><a
                                                href="{{url("comments/$product_id/$shop")}}"
                                                target="_blank">
                                            {{str_limit(($visitor['product']['products'][0]['title'] ?? 'No Title'),17) }}
                                        </a></i></h5>
                                <h6><i class=" fontello-home-outline"></i> From <span
                                            style="background: transparent;"><img style="margin-bottom: 5px;"
                                                                                  src="{{url("images/flags").'/'.strtolower($country_code).'.png' ?? ''}}"></span>
                                </h6>
                                <h6 style="margin-bottom: 20px;"><i
                                            class=" fontello-clock"></i>{{date('D, F y',strtotime($visitor['created_at'] ?? ''))}}
                                    y
                                    <span
                                            class="bg-black">{{date('g a',strtotime($visitor['created_at'] ?? ''))}}</span>
                                </h6>
                                <div class="visitors_images" style="    position: absolute;
    left: 56%;
    top: 43px;">
                                    <img width="50px"
                                         src="{{$visitor['product']['products'][0]['images'][0]['src'] ?? URL::asset('../storage/app/public/NoPicAvailable.png')}}">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php $counter ++; ?>
                    @endforeach
                </div>


            </div>
            <!-- /.box-body -->
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection

@section('javascript')
    <script src="{{URL::to('/js/flot/jquery.flot.js')}}"></script>
    <!-- FLOT RESIZE PLUGIN - allows the chart to redraw when the window is resized -->
    <script src="{{URL::to('/js/flot/jquery.flot.resize.min.js')}}"></script>
    <!-- FLOT PIE PLUGIN - also used to draw donut charts -->
    <script src="{{URL::to('/js/flot/jquery.flot.pie.min.js')}}"></script>
    <!-- FLOT CATEGORIES PLUGIN - Used to draw bar charts -->
    <script src="{{URL::to('/js/flot/jquery.flot.categories.min.js')}}"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
            <?php   $counter_days = 1;?>
        var ticks = [
                        @foreach($numbers_of_visitors_last_10_days as $keys=>$dates )
                        @if($counter_days <=1)
                [{{ltrim($keys,'0')}}, "days {{ltrim($keys,'0')}}"],
                        @else
                [{{ltrim($keys,'0')}},{{ltrim($keys,'0')}}],
                    @endif
                <?php   $counter_days ++;?>
                    @endforeach
            ];
        $(function () {
            "use strict";


            /*
             * LINE CHART
             * ----------
             */

            var line_data2 = [

                    @foreach($numbers_of_visitors_last_10_days as $keys=>$dates )
                [{{ltrim($keys,'0')}}, {{count($dates)}}],
                @endforeach
            ];
            var xaxisLabel = $("<div class='axisLabel xaxisLabel'></div>")
                .text("My X Label")
                .appendTo($('#line-chart'));

            $.plot("#line-chart", [line_data2], {

                grid: {
                    hoverable: true,
                    borderColor: "#E2E6EE",
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    tickColor: "#E2E6EE"
                },


                series: {
                    shadowSize: 2,
                    lines: {
                        show: true
                    },
                    points: {
                        show: true
                    }
                },
                colors: ["#333333", "#cccccc"],
                lines: {
                    fill: true,
                },
                yaxis: {
                    show: true,
                    tickFormatter: function (val, axis) { return val }


                },
                xaxis: {
                    show: true,
                    ticks: ticks,


                }

            });


        });


    </script>





@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it because of cached views. laravel make all the pages and save them in `storage/framework/views` directory.So that it won't have to make the pages from scratch in every request. And make the loading faster. 
type this on cmd after editing the files:

```
php artisan view:clear
```

Or you can delete them manually.
after that type this on cmd:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Then laravel has to make the pages and save them again.

Hope it would help!

Comment: I removed all of them  but it didn't work  I think it was outsource cache like cloudflare